# How do I convert lines coordinates to rectangles?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I found an algorithm online which generates mazes, and I want to make a game out of it. The algorithm draws lines around the border of cells which are used to generate a maze.

I would like to change these lines into rectangles in order to add collision to the game, however I've been having trouble doing so.

This is the code for the lines:

```
Top Line: pygame.draw.line(window, COLOR, (self.x, self.y), ((self.x + cellWidth), self.y), 2)
Right Line: pygame.draw.line(window, COLOR, ((self.x + cellWidth), self.y), ((self.x + cellWidth), (self.y + cellWidth)), 2)
Left Line: pygame.draw.line(window, COLOR, ((self.x + cellWidth), (self.y + cellWidth)),(self.x, (self.y + cellWidth)), 2)
Bottom Line: pygame.draw.line(window, COLOR, (self.x, (self.y + cellWidth)), (self.x, self.y), 2)
```

[image: The image shows how the lines look like from the above code]

This is my attempt at making them into rectangles:

```
Top Line: pygame.Rect((self.x, self.y), (cellWidth, 2))
Right Line: pygame.Rect(((self.x + cellWidth), self.y), (2, cellWidth))
Left Line: pygame.Rect((self.x, cellWidth + self.y), (2, cellWidth))
Bottom Line: pygame.Rect((self.x, self.y + cellWidth), (cellWidth, 2))
```

[image: The image shows how the rectangles draw look from the above code]

I just want the rectangles to be the same as the lines in the first image, however the calculations are wrong and the rectangles are drawn in the wrong places meaning there is no way to complete the maze.

Comment: Try comparing the results for each of the sides - top/left/right/bottom - as lines vs. rectangles. You should easily see which one(s) are different, and notice a pattern in how they are different, and thus fix the problem.

Comment: Why not change the algorithm a little bit so that it draws pygame Surfaces instead of lines.

Answer (score 0):

`2` corresponded to the thickness of the line, but in rectangle it is height. Your task requires to make lines just a bit thicker and get a rectangle.

```
wallWidth = 0.01
```

Suggested code

```
Top Line: pygame.Rect((self.x, self.y), (cellWidth, wallWidth))
Right Line: pygame.Rect(((self.x + cellWidth), self.y), (wallWidth, cellWidth))
Left Line: pygame.Rect((self.x, cellWidth + self.y), (wallWidth, cellWidth))
Bottom Line: pygame.Rect((self.x, self.y + cellWidth), (cellWidth, wallWidth))
```